# Input gives unknown syntax error - everything else works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on an RPG, and it is giving me unknown errors.
When I run this, it just says Syntax Error, but I can't find anything wrong.
Thanks!

```
name=str(input('Enter you name here:'))
adjective = str(input('Use one adjective to describe yourself:'))
rpg_class = input('Please choose your class. S = Soldier. W = Wizard. R = Rogue:'):
  if rpg_class=='S' or rpg_class=='s':
    print('\n')
    soldierdecisionone=input('You are a high esteemed soldier named ' + str(name) + '. Your city has been having frequent attacks from a mysterious beast in the middle of the night. You decide to explore into the wild to find out more. As you exit the city, you come to a fork in the road. Which way to you head? left/right'):
      if soldierdecisionone=='Left' or soldierdecisionone=='left':
        print('\n')
        soldierattackorc=input('You head left towards the woods. Just as you enter, a large orc jumps out from behind a bush and confronts you. It is at least twice your size. What do you do? attack/defend'):
          if soldierattackorc=='attack' or soldierattackorc=='Attack': print ('You attempted to attack the massive orc. Pretty bad idea, for your sword snaps on his thick hide. The orc beats you with his club until you die. GAME OVER')
          if soldierattackorc=='defend' or soldierattackorc=='Defend': soldierfindfood=input('You block the orc\'s attack with your shield. You run into the foods as fast as you can while he is stunned. As you explore deeper, you start to have aching hunger pains. To your left, you see a bush of white berries. To your right, you see a river surrounded by a few small animals. What do you do? forage/hunt')
```

Comment: It would help people if you provided details of the actual errors you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

```
rpg_class = input('Please choose your class. S = Soldier. W = Wizard. R = Rogue:'):
  if rpg_class=='S' or rpg_class=='s':
```

The error is here. input function should not end with ':'. Also it do not create a new block so no need of indentation for the next line starting with if

Syntax corrected code

```
name=str(input('Enter you name here:'))
adjective = str(input('Use one adjective to describe yourself:'))
rpg_class = input('Please choose your class. S = Soldier. W = Wizard. R = Rogue:')
if rpg_class=='S' or rpg_class=='s':
    print('\n')
    soldierdecisionone=input('You are a high esteemed soldier named ' + str(name) + '. Your city has been having frequent attacks from a mysterious beast in the middle of the night. You decide to explore into the wild to find out more. As you exit the city, you come to a fork in the road. Which way to you head? left/right')
    if soldierdecisionone=='Left' or soldierdecisionone=='left':
        print('\n')
        soldierattackorc=input('You head left towards the woods. Just as you enter, a large orc jumps out from behind a bush and confronts you. It is at least twice your size. What do you do? attack/defend')
        if soldierattackorc=='attack' or soldierattackorc=='Attack': print ('You attempted to attack the massive orc. Pretty bad idea, for your sword snaps on his thick hide. The orc beats you with his club until you die. GAME OVER')
        if soldierattackorc=='defend' or soldierattackorc=='Defend': soldierfindfood=input('You block the orc\'s attack with your shield. You run into the foods as fast as you can while he is stunned. As you explore deeper, you start to have aching hunger pains. To your left, you see a bush of white berries. To your right, you see a river surrounded by a few small animals. What do you do? forage/hunt')
```

You must try to work around your errors by reading the description of the error.